# ProtoBuf unable to serialize/deserialize a custom list of surrogate?

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

We are trying to serialize with protobuf, the following model:

```
[ProtoContract]
private class Container
{

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    //This does not make much sense in this example, but this is the easiest representation of our biggest model
    public ItemCollection<ISomeOtherInterface> ContainedObjects { get; set; }


    public Container()
    {
        ContainedObjects=  new ItemCollection<ISomeOtherInterface>();
    }
}


[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault = true)]
public interface IAnyConfigurationNode
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    String Name { get; set; }
}
[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault = true)]
private interface ISomeOtherInterface : IAnyConfigurationNode
{
    int Order { get; set; }
}
[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault = true)]
private abstract class SomeBaseType : IAnyConfigurationNode
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault = true)]
private class SomeType : SomeBaseType, ISomeOtherInterface
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

Since we reference(in this case it does make much sense, but we have some business case where we have to) the `SomeType` though another interface that is not in the `IAnyConfigurationNode`->`SomeBaseType`->`SomeType` tree(we cannot says that `SomeType` extends `SomeBaseType` AND `ISomeOtherInterface`, which would be kind of multi-heriting in ProtoBuf), we have made a Surrogate, that basically save the object as a `IAnyConfigurationNode` instead of a `` `ISomeOtherInterface`:

```
[ProtoContract]
private class ProtoSurrogate<T> where T: class, IAnyConfigurationNode
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private IAnyConfigurationNode ContainedObject { get; set; }

    [ProtoConverter]
    public static ProtoSurrogate<T> To(T toBeSurogated)
    {
        return toBeSurogated == null ? null : new ProtoSurrogate<T>() { ContainedObject = toBeSurogated};
    }

    [ProtoConverter]
    public static T From(ProtoSurrogate<T> surrogate)
    {
        return surrogate?.ContainedObject as T;
    }
}
```

The interessting part in the Container:
`ItemCollection` is a custom condition(in our real case the class using this collection provide some delegate to have some callback action(like setting itself as the parent of the newly added item within its list), is like this:

```
[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault = true)]
public class ItemCollection<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]//Only thing that is serialized here
    private readonly List<T> m_items;
    public int Count => m_items.Count;
    public ItemCollection(){m_items = new List<T>();}
    public void Add(T item){m_items.Add(item);}
    public bool Contains(T item){return m_items.Contains(item);}
    public void Clear(){m_items.Clear();}
    public void Sort(){m_items.Sort();}
    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator(){return m_items.GetEnumerator();}
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(){return m_items.GetEnumerator();}
    void ICollection<T>.CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex){m_items.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);}
    bool ICollection<T>.IsReadOnly => false;
    bool ICollection<T>.Remove(T item){return m_items.Remove(item);}
}
```

We have the heritance/surrogates specified like this:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(ISomeOtherInterface), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(ProtoSurrogate<ISomeOtherInterface>));
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(IAnyConfigurationNode)].AddSubType(1000, typeof(SomeBaseType));
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(SomeBaseType)].AddSubType(1000000, typeof(SomeType));
```

Then at the end, I've only an UnitTest that does the following:

```
SomeType node = new SomeType { Name = "Name one", Order = 1 ,Id = 1};
Container container = new Container();
container.ContainedObjects.Add(node);
byte[] bytes;
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Serializer.Serialize(stream, container);
    bytes= stream.ToArray();
}
Container container2;
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    container2= Serializer.Deserialize<Container>(stream);
}
```

When this is executed, we have this error:

```
System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'Test.ProtoBufSurrogateTest2+ProtoSurrogate`1[ProtoBufSurrogateTest2+ISomeOtherInterface]' cannot be converted to type 'Test.ProtoBufSurrogateTest2+IAnyConfigurationNode'.
   at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.PropertyDecorator.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\Serializers\PropertyDecorator.cs:line 82
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.TypeSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\Serializers\TypeSerializer.cs:line 227
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.SurrogateSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\Serializers\SurrogateSerializer.cs:line 129
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 832
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\ProtoReader.cs:line 607
   at ProtoBuf.BclHelpers.ReadNetObject(Object value, ProtoReader source, Int32 key, Type type, NetObjectOptions options) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\BclHelpers.cs:line 616
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.NetObjectSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\Serializers\NetObjectSerializer.cs:line 45
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.TagDecorator.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\Serializers\TagDecorator.cs:line 80
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.ListDecorator.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\Serializers\ListDecorator.cs:line 563
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.PropertyDecorator.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\Serializers\PropertyDecorator.cs:line 77
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.TypeSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\Serializers\TypeSerializer.cs:line 227
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 832
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore(ProtoReader reader, Type type, Object value, Boolean noAutoCreate) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 744
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type type, SerializationContext context) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 607
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type type) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 584
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize[T](Stream source) in D:\Dev\BB\Src\External\Protobuf-Net2\Serializer.cs:line 84
   at Test.ProtoBufSurrogateTest2.TestSurrogateHavingReferenceType() in D:\XXXXXXXTest\ProtoBufSurrogateTest2.cs:line 41
```

The fun part is that IF in `Container` class, I just change the type of `ContainedObject`for a simple `List` instead of `ItemCollection`, everything is working well.

I've taken the ProtoBuf code, to investigate a little bit, and it seems that it's not the same serializer that is used. If we have a Custom List, at some point we use the `TypeSerializer`, and if we use a standard list, we use the `SubItemSerializer`. In this case, we call pretty quick the `BclHelper.ReadNetObject`, which tries to `Trap` the first "next" object, which in this case is the surrogate. In the normal case, we don't `Trap` the surrogate, but the child item.

I understand it makes a lot of code, so I've put in place a full-working UnitTest showing the issue:
https://pastebin.com/auhm35EH

It makes 3 days that I'm trying to debug this, I really hope that @MarcGravell will be able to assist a little bit.

Comment: I really hope that @MarcGravell will be able to assist, we are pretty stuck with this :(

Comment: I'll get to it, but I'm on limited hours at the moment and have a backlog of other things :)

Comment: @MarcGravell Let me know if there is something I can do to help you. I tried to understand how it was done inside your lib, but not that easy to get everything.

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't want to press you at all, but really a lot of pressure on my shoulders because of this issue, could you at least give me a timeframe when you think you could take a look at it? The whole release is on standby due to this point, and the managers are starting to think we should move to another serializer(which I don't agree). So if at least I could have an idea of when you could take this in account, this would definitely help a lot. And I guess that with the UnitTest reproducing exactly the issue, this should be easy to understand?